# Solving non linear differential equation.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{x'(t)}{x(t)}\right)=x(t)-x^2(t)$ where $x'(t)=\frac{d}{dt}x(t)$
What reasoning (if it exists) I can apply to solve this differential equation?
Thanks.

Comment: A good motivation for Julián's method is to notice that the $\frac{x'}{x}$ term is just $(\ln x)'$, so the desired function is the exponential of another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x=e^u$; then $u$ satisfies de differential equation
$$
u''=e^u-e^{2u}.
$$
Multiply by $u´$ and integrate once to get
$$
\frac12(u')^2=e^u-\frac12\,e^{2u}+C_1.
$$
This is a differential equation in separeted variables, whose solution is
$$
\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{2\,e^u-e^{2u}+2\,C_1}}=\pm t+C_2.
$$

Comment: If we let $x=e^u$, then $\dfrac{d}{du}(e^u/e^u)=0=e^u-e^{2u}$. Aren't we thinking of $x$ as a function of $u$? So what does $u''$ mean (does it mean $-\dfrac{1}{x^2}$)? I'm just curious and wanting to learn. =) Shouldn't one write $(xx''-(x')^2)/x^2=e^u-e^{2u}$? Here on the LHS, I just took the derivative of $x'/x$ with respect to $u$.

Comment: @math-visitor $x$ and $u$ are unknowns functions of the independent variable $t$. The definition of $u$ is $x(t)=e^{u(t)}$.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was speculating that, but I wasn't sure. Thank you Julian!